# How to determine the Dropbox folder location programmatically?

Tags: python, directory, dropbox

I have a script that is intended to be run by multiple users on multiple computers, and they don't all have their Dropbox folders in their respective home directories. I'd hate to have to hard code paths in the script. I'd much rather figure out the path programatically.

Any suggestions welcome.

EDIT:
I am not using the Dropbox API in the script, the script simply reads files in a specific Dropbox folder shared between the users. The only thing I need is the path to the Dropbox folder, as I of course already know the relative path within the Dropbox file structure.

EDIT:
If it matters, I am using Windows 7.

Comment: What is the script supposed to do? Are you using the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9660280/how-do-i-programmatically-locate-my-dropbox-folder-using-c?rq=1). Setting `s` equal to the 2nd line in `~\AppData\Roaming\Dropbox\host.db` and then decoding it with base64 gives the path.

```
def _get_appdata_path():
    import ctypes
    from ctypes import wintypes, windll
    CSIDL_APPDATA = 26
    _SHGetFolderPath = windll.shell32.SHGetFolderPathW
    _SHGetFolderPath.argtypes = [wintypes.HWND,
                                 ctypes.c_int,
                                 wintypes.HANDLE,
                                 wintypes.DWORD,
                                 wintypes.LPCWSTR]
    path_buf = wintypes.create_unicode_buffer(wintypes.MAX_PATH)
    result = _SHGetFolderPath(0, CSIDL_APPDATA, 0, 0, path_buf)
    return path_buf.value

def dropbox_home():
    from platform import system
    import base64
    import os.path
    _system = system()
    if _system in ('Windows', 'cli'):
        host_db_path = os.path.join(_get_appdata_path(),
                                    'Dropbox',
                                    'host.db')
    elif _system in ('Linux', 'Darwin'):
        host_db_path = os.path.expanduser('~'
                                          '/.dropbox'
                                          '/host.db')
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Unknown system={}'
                           .format(_system))
    if not os.path.exists(host_db_path):
        raise RuntimeError("Config path={} doesn't exists"
                           .format(host_db_path))
    with open(host_db_path, 'r') as f:
        data = f.read().split()

    return base64.b64decode(data[1])
```

Comment: To find host.db on Windows: `host_db_path = os.path.join(winpaths.get_appdata(), 'Dropbox', 'host.db')` Instead of `winpaths` you could [use ctypes directly with `CSIDL_APPDATA`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/626927/4279). On Linux, OSX: `host_db_path = os.path.expanduser('~/.dropbox/host.db')`

Comment: The line `raise RuntimeError("Config path={} doesn't exists".format(p))` gives `NameError: global name 'p' is not defined`.

Comment: I think it should be `raise RuntimeError("Config path={} doesn't exist".format(host_db_path))`

Comment: The dropbox_home() function doesn't work on Android.

Comment: The dropbox host.db file doesn't exist anymore in latest versions.. Grr.. Looking for a new solution.

Answer (score 13):

There is an answer to this on Dropbox Help Center - [How can I programmatically find the Dropbox folder paths?](https://www.dropbox.com/help/4584)

### Short version:

Use `~/.dropbox/info.json` or `%APPDATA%\Dropbox\info.json`

### Long version:

Access the valid `%APPDATA%` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%` location this way:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import json

try:
    json_path = (Path(os.getenv('LOCALAPPDATA'))/'Dropbox'/'info.json').resolve()
except FileNotFoundError:
    json_path = (Path(os.getenv('APPDATA'))/'Dropbox'/'info.json').resolve()

with open(str(json_path)) as f:
    j = json.load(f)

personal_dbox_path = Path(j['personal']['path'])
business_dbox_path = Path(j['business']['path'])
```

Comment: tx!! very uselful, works great with windows

Answer (score 1):

You could search the file system using `os.walk`. The *Dropbox* folder is probably within the home directory of the user, so to save some time you could limit your search to that. Example:

```
import os
dropbox_folder = None

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(os.path.expanduser('~')):
    for subdirname in dirnames:
        if(subdirname == 'Dropbox'):
            dropbox_folder = os.path.join(dirname, subdirname)
            break
    if dropbox_folder:
        break

# dropbox_folder now contains the full path to the Dropbox folder, or
# None if the folder wasn't found
```

---

Alternatively you could prompt the user for the Dropbox folder location, or make it configurable via a config file.

Comment: I did actually implement this, but then I found out some users had put their Dropbox folders outside their home directory...

Comment: Then simply search the entire filesystem instead. It will only search until it finds a folder called Dropbox. I still think the best solution would be to prompt the user though.

Comment: This will find the user's Dropbox application folder, but that's not necessarily the locate where Dropbox actually stores the user's data files (there's default but it's user definable). That information is stored in a `host.db` file located within that directory.

Answer (score 1):

This adaptation based on [J.F. Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian)'s suggestion works for me on Ubuntu:

```
os.path.expanduser('~/Dropbox')
```

And to actually set the working directory to be there:

```
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Dropbox'))
```

Comment: only if the dropbox is actually installed there.

Answer (score 1):

Note: *answer is valid for Dropbox v2.8 and higher*

**Windows**

```
jq -r ".personal.path" < %APPDATA%\Dropbox\info.json
```

This needs [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) - JSON parser utility to be installed. If you are happy user of Chocolatey package manager, just run `choco install jq` before.

**Linux**

```
jq -r ".personal.path" < ~/.dropbox/info.json
```

Just similarly to Windows install [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) using package manager of your distro.

Answer (score 1):

Note: requires Dropbox >= 2.8

[Dropbox now stores the paths in json format in a file called `info.json`](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/4584). It is located in one of the two following locations:

```
%APPDATA%\Dropbox\info.json
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Dropbox\info.json
```

I can access the `%APPDATA%` environment variable in Python by `os.environ['APPDATA']`, however I check both that and `os.environ['LOCALAPPDATA']`. Then I convert the JSON into a dictionary and read the `'path'` value under the appropriate Dropbox (business or personal).

Calling `get_dropbox_location()` from the code below will return the filepath of the business Dropbox, while `get_dropbox_location('personal')` will return the file path of the personal Dropbox.

```
import os
import json

def get_dropbox_location(account_type='business'):
    """
    Returns a string of the filepath of the Dropbox for this user

    :param account_type: str, 'business' or 'personal'
    """
    info_path = _get_dropbox_info_path()
    info_dict = _get_dictionary_from_path_to_json(info_path)
    return _get_dropbox_path_from_dictionary(info_dict, account_type)

def _get_dropbox_info_path():
    """
    Returns filepath of Dropbox file info.json
    """
    path = _create_dropox_info_path('APPDATA')
    if path:
        return path
    return _create_dropox_info_path('LOCALAPPDATA')

def _create_dropox_info_path(appdata_str):
    r"""
    Looks up the environment variable given by appdata_str and combines with \Dropbox\info.json

    Then checks if the info.json exists at that path, and if so returns the filepath, otherwise
    returns False
    """
    path = os.path.join(os.environ[appdata_str], r'Dropbox\info.json')
    if os.path.exists(path):
        return path
    return False

def _get_dictionary_from_path_to_json(info_path):
    """
    Loads a json file and returns as a dictionary
    """
    with open(info_path, 'r') as f:
        text = f.read()

    return json.loads(text)

def _get_dropbox_path_from_dictionary(info_dict, account_type):
    """
    Returns the 'path' value under the account_type dictionary within the main dictionary
    """
    return info_dict[account_type]['path']
```

This is a pure Python solution, unlike the other solution using `info.json`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is you could go searching for the `.dropbox.cache` directory which (at least on Mac and Linux) is a hidden folder in the Dropbox directory.

I am fairly certain that Dropbox stores its preferences in an encrypted `.dbx` container, so extracting it using the same method that Dropbox uses is not trivial.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on Win7. The use of `getEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA")` instead of `os.getenv('APPDATA')` supports Unicode filepaths -- see question titled [Problems with umlauts in python appdata environvent variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608200/problems-with-umlauts-in-python-appdata-environvent-variable).

```
import base64
import ctypes
import os

def getEnvironmentVariable(name):
    """ read windows native unicode environment variables """
    # (could just use os.environ dict in Python 3)
    name = unicode(name) # make sure string argument is unicode
    n = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetEnvironmentVariableW(name, None, 0)
    if not n:
        return None
    else:
        buf = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(u'\0'*n)
        ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetEnvironmentVariableW(name, buf, n)
        return buf.value

def getDropboxRoot():
    # find the path for Dropbox's root watch folder from its sqlite host.db database.
    # Dropbox stores its databases under the currently logged in user's %APPDATA% path.
    # If you have installed multiple instances of dropbox under the same login this only finds the 1st one.
    # Dropbox stores its databases under the currently logged in user's %APPDATA% path.
    # usually "C:\Documents and Settings\<login_account>\Application Data"
    sConfigFile = os.path.join(getEnvironmentVariable("APPDATA"),
                               'Dropbox', 'host.db')

    # return null string if can't find or work database file.
    if not os.path.exists(sConfigFile):
        return None

    # Dropbox Watch Folder Location is base64 encoded as the last line of the host.db file.
    with open(sConfigFile) as dbxfile:
        for sLine in dbxfile:
            pass

    # decode last line, path to dropbox watch folder with no trailing slash.
    return base64.b64decode(sLine)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print getDropboxRoot()
```