# JSON parsing of Dropbox Metadata in python

Tags: python, json, windows-7, dropbox-api

Using Dropbox APIs, I am able to get view of all the folders in the root folder and using metadata, I can print all the information from JSON on the screen.

For example, a sample output would be like

```
{
    'bytes': 0,
    'contents': [
        {
           'bytes': 0,
           'icon': 'folder',
           'is_dir': True,
           'modified': 'Thu, 25 Aug 2011 00:03:15 +0000',
           'path': '/Sample Folder',
           'rev': '803beb471',
           'revision': 8,
           'root': 'dropbox',
           'size': '0 bytes',
           'thumb_exists': False
        }, 
        {
           'bytes': 77,
           'icon': 'page_white_text',
           'is_dir': False,
           'mime_type': 'text/plain',
           'modified': 'Wed, 20 Jul 2011 22:04:50 +0000',
           'path': '/magnum-opus.txt',
           'rev': '362e2029684fe',
           'revision': 221922,
           'root': 'dropbox',
           'size': '77 bytes',
           'thumb_exists': False
        }
    ],
    'hash': 'efdac89c4da886a9cece1927e6c22977',
    'icon': 'folder',
    'is_dir': True,
    'path': '/',
    'root': 'app_folder',
    'size': '0 bytes',
    'thumb_exists': False
}
```

I am not sure, how can I get elements of 'contents' array and then recursively, get files using 'path' attribute.

And my ultimate goal is to get list of all files in `Dropbox` folder. Is there any better way to get list of all files?

I have tried following code:

```
folder_metadata = self.api_client.metadata('/Photos')
print "-----------------------------"
print "path:", folder_metadata['path']
for s in folder_metadata['contents']:
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(s['path']):
        for filename in filenames:
            var = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            print var
```

and its output is:

```
-----------------------------
path: /Photos
```

How can I get an absolute path?

Comment: Do you have the same files on your harddisk (as synchronized by Dropbox)?

Comment: Yes, I think, it needs an absolute path for 'path' to find out all the files in the folder. I have tried the same code with hard-coded absolute path and it does give me list of files. So, all I need is absolute path.

Comment: I tried this solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118162/how-can-i-get-the-dropbox-folder-location-programmatically-in-python) but it checks for 'hosts.db' which is in C: folder but my own Dropbox folder is in E: , so this is wrong.

Comment: You are correct you need a path, and that question you link to should provide the correct answer; the top-voted answer retrieves the registry key that Dropbox itself has set; if your dropbox folder is on E: then that's a problem with Dropbox itself and I don't think there is anything we can do about that from Python.

Comment: In any case, the API does *not* provide you with the local path for your Dropbox files. That is the responsibility of the Dropbox application installed on your machine instead.

Comment: Did you check [this script](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/PyDropboxValues) yet? It's linked in a comment on the other question.

Comment: "An error occured: Unhandled DB schema version 2" Thats what I got from that script. Anywya, thank you Martijn for your help. I will provide path to Dropbox to my function now. =)