# Locating Dropbox folder

Tags: java

I am working on a personal project in java that will (in theory) use a file in dropbox for data storage and it will be edited across multiple computers and devices. However, these device will not necessariyl have the same file structure due to OS Differences (Linux, Win8, Win7). How would I get the location of the dropbox folder within the code in java?
I looked online already and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118162/how-can-i-get-the-dropbox-folder-location-programmatically-in-python) regarding doing this in python as well as a c# example linked in the python example, but am not sure how to apply that in java.

Comment: Not all devices will even have a dropbox directory; there's no requirement for a dropbox user to sync locally by installing the integration.

Comment: durgas's answer was what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 System.getProperty("user.home")+File.separator+"Dropbox";
```