# Running python script with new directories

Tags: python, path

I have recently begun working on a new computer.  All my python files and my data are in the dropbox folder, so having access to the data is not a problem.  However, the "`user`" name on the file has changed.  Thus, none of my `os.chdir()` operations work. Obviously, I can modify all of my scripts using a find and replace, but that won't help if I try using my old computer.

Currently, all the directories called look something like this:
"`C:\Users\Old_Username\Dropbox\Path`"
and the files I want to access on the new computer look like:
"`C:\Users\New_Username\Dropbox\Path`"

Is there some sort of `try/except` I can build into my script so it goes through the various path-name options if the first attempt doesn't work?

Thanks!

Comment: I really didnt get it, what is your problem actually can you be more specific please? If accessing is not a problem, so what is?

Comment: I have dozens of specific directory paths listed in my program. I could theoretically get the code to work on the new machine if I went through and changed every single path.  However, this is not practical (as it would break the code on my first machine, for example).  I want to know a more general method for changing all the paths in the code.

Comment: Well you can use regular expressions for that probably, did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

Thought the file *sq.py* with these codes(your olds):

```
C:/Users/Old_Username/Dropbox/Path

for x in range:
    #something
def Something():
    #something...

C:/Users/Old_Username/Dropbox/Path
```

Then a new .py file run these codes:

```
with open("sq.py","r") as f:
    for x in f.readlines():
        y=x
        if re.findall("C:/Users/Old_Username/Dropbox/Path",x) == ['C:/Users/Old_Username/Dropbox/Path']:
            x="C:/Users/New_Username/Dropbox/Path"
            y=y.replace(y,x)

        print (y)
```

Output is:

```
C:/Users/New_Username/Dropbox/Path
for x in range:
    #something

def Something():
    #something...

C:/Users/New_Username/Dropbox/Path
```

Hope its your solution at least can give you some idea dealing with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution will involve editing your code; so if you are going to edit it anyway - its best to make it generic enough so it works on all platforms.

In the answer to [How can I get the Dropbox folder location programmatically in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118162/how-can-i-get-the-dropbox-folder-location-programmatically-in-python) there is a code snippet that you can use if this problem is limited to dropbox.

For a more generic solution, you can use environment variables to figure out the home directory of a user.

On Windows the home directory is location is stored in `%UserProfile%`, on Linux and OSX it is in `$HOME`. Luckily Python will take care of all this for you with [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

```
import os
home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
```

Using `home_dir` will ensure that the same path is resolved on all systems.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that eventually I will move or rename my projects or scripts, I always use this code right at the beginning:

```
import os, inspect

this_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))

this_script = inspect.stack()[0][1]
this_script_name = this_script.split('/')[-1]
```

If you call your script not with the full but a relative path, then this_script will also not contain a full path. this_dir however will always be the full path to the directory.