# Python sqlite3 connect with special characters in path

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I have an application that is compiled with PyInstaller that uses a sqlite database. Everything works fine until a user with special characters in their name runs the software. Even simple code like this:

```
import sqlite3
path = "C:\\Users\\Jøen\\test.db"

db = sqlite3.connect(path)
```

Results in a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

I have tried all kinds of combinations including using `chardet` to detect the encoding and then converting to UTF-8 but that didn't work either. All of my usual Python encoding/decoding tricks are failing me at this point.

Has anyone successfully opened a SQLite DB in Python that has special characters in a path?

So if any of you have international or special characters in your user path, some test code to potentially help me:

```
import os
import sqlite3
path = os.path.expanduser("~")
sqlite3.connect(path + "\\test.db")
```

Comment: Is `sqlite3.connect(db)` a typo? I'm guessing `sqlite3.connect(path)`?

Comment: Correct. Edited. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues:

- `\t` is a *tab character*, `\U` is the start of a 8-hex-digit Unicode character escape.
- You'd need to encode to the *platform filesystem encoding*, [`sys.getfilesystemencoding()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding), which on Windows is usually UTF-16 (little endian) or MBCS (Multi-byte character set, really meaning *any of our supported multi-byte encodings, including UTF-16), but *not* UTF-8. Or just pass in a Unicode string and let Python worry about this for you.

On Python 2, the following should work:

```
path = ur"C:\Users\Jøen\test.db"
```

This uses a *raw unicode string literal*, meaning that it'll a) not interpret `\t` as a tab but as two separate characters and b) produce a Unicode string for Python then to encode to the correct filesystem encoding.

Alternatively, on Windows forward slashes are also acceptable as separators, or you could *double* the backslashes to properly escape them:

```
path = u"C:/Users/Jøen/test.db"
path = u"C:\\Users\\Jøen\\test.db"
```

On Python 3, just drop the `u` and still *not* encode:

```
path = r"C:\Users\Jøen\test.db"
```

Building a path from the home directory, use Unicode strings everywhere and use `os.path.join()` to build your path. Unfortunately, `os.path.expanduser()` is *not* Unicode-aware on Python 2 (see [bug 28171](http://bugs.python.org/issue18171)), so using it requires decoding using `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` but this can actually fail (see [Problems with umlauts in python appdata environvent variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608200/problems-with-umlauts-in-python-appdata-environvent-variable) as to why). You could of course try anyway:

```
path = os.path.expanduser("~").decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(path, u"test.db"))
```

But instead relying on retrieving the Unicode value of the environment variables would ensure you got an uncorrupted value instead; building on [Problems with umlauts in python appdata environvent variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608200/problems-with-umlauts-in-python-appdata-environvent-variable), that could look like:

```
import ctypes
import os

def getEnvironmentVariable(name):
    name= unicode(name) # make sure string argument is unicode
    n= ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetEnvironmentVariableW(name, None, 0)
    if n==0:
        return None
    buf= ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(u'\0'*n)
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetEnvironmentVariableW(name, buf, n)
    return buf.value

if 'HOME' in os.environ: 
    userhome = getEnvironmentVariable('HOME')
elif 'USERPROFILE' in os.environ:
    userhome = getEnvironmentVariable('USERPROFILE')

 sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(userhome, u"test.db"))
```

Comment: Sorry again mistyping from my VM. The path is double encoded with slashes. Using `ur` ends up just throwing an ascii encoding problem.

Comment: `\U` would also cause problems using python3

Comment: Using the `u` with `expanduser` throws an encoding error:

`>>> path = os.path.expanduser(u"~")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 311, in expanduser
    return userhome + path[i:]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 10: ordinal
 not in range(128)
>>>`

Comment: Low on time, but that may be a bug in older 2.7 versions. Will investigate.

Comment: Bah, humbug. It's considered [not a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue18171) in Python 2. I'll update to using `sys.getdefaultencoding()` since the data comes from an environment variable.

Comment: @user6026624 there; Windows is a difficult beast to deal with sometimes. Untested for now because I have no access to a Windows machine at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I found will actually work without having to deal with encoding (which I never did find a solution to) is to use the answer from here:

[How to get Windows short file name in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23598289/how-to-get-windows-short-file-name-in-python)

The short name appears to always have the encoded characters removed based on my testing. I realize this is a kludge but I could not find another way.